# SendKeys.SendWait taking too much time C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, set, sendkeys

I am trying to control an external application through c# code and for that I am using SendKeys control to set the values inside a textbox after setting its focus.

The external application is a wpf application and I have already tried SendKeys.Send and it does not work with WPF application.

I am using SendKeys.SendWait to set the textbox value like below,

```
SendKeys.SendWait(TextValue);
```

The above piece of code is taking about 30-40 seconds to set the value in the textbox. The TextValue contains value from XML which will be dynamic and characters are numbers only and the length of the variable is aroun 10-11 digit.

If i pass like this,

```
SendKeys.SendWait("123456");
```

then it works great but I am not sure why is it taking too much time when i pass the variable.

Is there any way i can make it work faster?

Answer (score 0):

A little workaround to make it faster would be using the clipboard to store the variable's content and then sending the keys to paste in the textbox. Here's the code to interact with the clipboard :

```
Clipboard.SetText(YourVariable); // Makes the clipboard content become your variable
SendKeys.SendWait("^V"); // sends CTRL + V to paste text
```

You can see more about the [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.8) class if you want to keep what was in the clipboard before your code changes it for example.